# SQLCMD can't connect when in shell script

Tags: sql-server, shell, sh, sqlcmd

I'm actually writing a little script that call sqlcmd.
There it is :

```
sqlcmd -S localhost\SQLEXPRESS -E -i Select_All.sql -o All_Tables_Name.txt
```

When i write this as a cmd line it works well.

When i put it in a .sh file sqlcmd can't connect to the Database and i get these errors :

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. .
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

I tried to change the -S argument with the Machine name or by '.' but still doesn't work.

Can someone explain me why is it different when i write it as a command line and when i launch it from a script Please ? (like "`sh MyScript.sh`")

Thank you.

Comment: Are you running your script locally? Is your instance really named?

Comment: Yes i'm running my script locally, i tried with both Powershell and command prompt (my Database is stocked locally too).
And yes my instance is named that's what you can see after the -S argument ( MachineName\Instance ) isn't it ?
But i want to point out that the command line works perfectly. But when i copy / paste it in a .sh file and execute it, it doesn't work...

Comment: Yes, -S localhost\SQLEXPRESS is correct in your case (running locally), but the error says that server cannot be found, so or the name is incorrect (in this case try this alternatives: .\SQLEXPRESS or pc_explicit_name\SQLEXPRESS), or it's not using shared memory but for some reason it tries tcp\ip and then named pipes, and in this case you should check out your protocols configuration if they are enabled and run sql browser

Comment: I already tried to do .\SQLEXPRESS and pc_name\SQLEXPRESS doesn't change anything.

"TCP/IP connection" is enabled but "Named pipes connection" isn't. I'll try to enable it or force the TCP/IP connection with sqlcmd. Thank you !

Comment: what about other protocols? if the name is correct, it may be other protocol that it tries to use. As far as I remember, Express has only shared memory enabled by default, try to enable tcp and launch sql server browser

Comment: I forced sqlcmd to connect with TCP/IP protocol

`sqlcmd -S tcp:127.0.0.1,61672 -i All_Tables.sql -o All_Tables_Name.txt`

Tahnk you for your help !

Comment: when it uses tcp/ip, it should resolve instance name, so you need SQL Server Browser running

Comment: Bravo, so you needn't browser. Passing ip,port you give it all he needs to connect